# Loading a .obj file all black

Tags: three.js

I've successfully loaded a 3d model that I triangulated using Blender. Trouble is its all black and I can't figure out how to get it to show color or textures.

I have an ambient light initialized like this:

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene;

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75, (window.innerWidth) / (window.innerHeight),
        1, 10000);
camera.position.x = 500;
camera.position.z = 100;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
camera.rotateZ(90 * Math.PI / 180);

scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff));

populate();

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { keydown(event);
});
```

}

Here's the .mtl that goes with the .obj
Blender MTL File: 'mq9.blend'
Material Count: 4

newmtl Material__69
Ns 9.803922
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.225882 0.225882 0.225882
Ks 0.900000 0.900000 0.900000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl _6___Default
Ns 19.607843
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.800000 0.800000
Ks 0.900000 0.900000 0.900000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

## map_Kd missile.jpg

newmtl mq_9
Ns 31.372549
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.800000 0.800000
Ks 0.990000 0.990000 0.990000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

## map_Kd predator.jpg

## map_Bump predator_Normal.jpg

newmtl mq_90
Ns 31.372549
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.800000 0.800000
Ks 0.990000 0.990000 0.990000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

## map_Kd predator.jpg

## map_Bump predator_Normal.jpg

The various .jpgs are all found but for some reason they don't seem to be rendering by three.js. I'm wondering if the jpgs need to be modified somehow to reflect the triangulation?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: So to help you out, I've put a live version of this program up.  Its at: http://aggregation.co/3d    Its a basic flight simulator type thing.  The pageup key increases your velocity, the pagedown key decreases your velocity.   The arrow keys are used for steering.  Thanks.  FM

Comment: Did you add lights to your scene?

Comment: If you look at the code above, you'll see there is an ambient light.

Comment: Interesting, I added six point lights at the 6 axes and I can now see some detail on the light gray rendering.  While this is better, I'd still like to get the images to render on the model.  Look at the program for the updated version:  http://aggregation.co/3d

Comment: Read about ambient reflectance. It should normally equal diffuse refectance. Set Ka values equal to Kd values. You should see the ambient light effect as a start.

Comment: Consider updating to the current version of three.js.